# Which Model to use in R? (Psychological Momentum in Sports)

Tags: r, model, binary

As you saw in the title im searching for a good model to explain the following:

I have a data set of the results of Real Madrid the last 17 years and need to find out, once they were losing and scored after that, if the scored goal has an influence to turn around the game. (Ex. Real Madrid - Betis Sevilla 0:1, than Madrid scores a goal - 1:1, has this goal now an influence on their performance for the rest of the game?)

I was thinking that the dependent variable could be a binary one: 1-Madrid scores (in my example it would be the 2:1) 0-Madrid doesn't score.

I hope somebody can help me.
Thanks in advance

Kind regards
J.K.

Comment: A binary dependent variable usually means logit regression.

Comment: Thank you. Would you also recommend a binary variable or is there in your opinion a better model to use?

Comment: Well, you want to find out if scoring after being behind has an influence on them winning the game (which is kind of trivial, but that's up to you). I'd restrict my data to cases where Madrid was initially behind, set win/loss as dependent variable and then use scored/did not score as a binary independent variable. But you do realize that them not scoring after being behind has to result in a loss and therefore this whole analysis is kind of obsolete, right?